# Trying to get emails from the past 3 days from outlook, it almost works, but it's skipping emails, any idea why? [code inside]

Tags: python, api, email, outlook

So here's the code ...

```
import win32com.client, datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def checkTime():
    date_filter_unformated = datetime.date.today() - timedelta(days=3)
    date_filter = date_filter_unformated.strftime("%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S")
    current_message = all_messages.GetPrevious()
    message_time = current_message.ReceivedTime
    df_list = list(date_filter)
    mt_list = list(str(message_time))
    df_month, mt_month = int(''.join([df_list[0],df_list[1]])), int(''.join([mt_list[0],mt_list[1]]))
    df_day, mt_day = int(''.join([df_list[3],df_list[4]])), int(''.join([mt_list[3],mt_list[4]]))
    df_year, mt_year = int(''.join([df_list[6],df_list[7]])), int(''.join([mt_list[6],mt_list[7]]))
    if mt_year < df_year:
        return "Old"
    elif mt_year == df_year:
        if mt_month < df_month:
            return "Old"
        elif mt_month == df_month:
            if mt_day < df_day:
                return "Old"
            else:
                CurrentMessage(current_message)
                return "Pass"
        elif mt_month > df_month:
            CurrentMessage(current_message)
            return "Pass"

def CurrentMessage(cm):
    print cm.Sender, cm.ReceivedTime
    #

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. Can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder

all_messages = inbox.Items
current_message = all_messages.GetLast()

while True:
    if checkTime() == "Pass":
        continue
    if checkTime() == "Old":
        break
```

So it should return the name of sender and date recieved of all emails within the past 3 days, but instead, it returns some of the emails from the 26th (today) and then all of the emails from the 23rd (3 days ago), with none from in between. I have no idea what's causing it to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming that messages in the Items collection are sorted. The collection will be sorted in a particular order only after you call Items.Sort ( `all_messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", true)` in your case).